# JavaFX TableView CheckBoxTableCell with boolean instead of SimpleBooleanProperty

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx, tableview

I'm wondering how I could use the CheckBoxTableCell without a ObservableProperty. I'm using a simple boolean because I want to serialize the Data to my DerbyDB.

For sure there would be the possibility to make a SimpleBooleanProperty and annote it with `@Transient` and wrap it around my normal `boolean active`.

My boolean value is shown properly but I'm not able to store the new value after the Checkbox in my Tableview is clicked.

```
private void setupColActive() {
    colActive.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<UserVillage, Boolean>("active"));
    colActive.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(colActive));       
    colActive.setEditable(true);
}
```

I've tried it with `colActive.setOnEditCancel`, `colActive.setOnEditCommit` and `colActive.setOnEditStart` in combo with print outlines but I'm not able to catch the new Value to store it. I'd like to find a way to get it working without wrapping into a `@Transient SimpleBooleanProperty active`.

Comment: My preferred solution here would be to use `ObservableProperty`s and support serialization just by defining `readObject()` and `writeObject()` methods. Is there a good reason not to do that? The alternative is fairly ugly: create a property specifically for the check box, and map to it via the `selectedStateCallback`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The serialization issue does not prevent you from using JavaFX properties in the model class `UserVillage`. I would recommend using these properties and just customizing the serialization mechanism by defining `readObject` and `writeObject` methods. Here's a demo of a class defined like this:

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
    private StringProperty name ;
    private IntegerProperty value ;
    private BooleanProperty active ;

    public Item(String name, int value, boolean active) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name) ;
        this.value = new SimpleIntegerProperty(value);
        this.active = new SimpleBooleanProperty(active);
    }


    public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public final java.lang.String getName() {
        return this.nameProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
        this.nameProperty().set(name);
    }
    public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public final int getValue() {
        return this.valueProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setValue(final int value) {
        this.valueProperty().set(value);
    }
    public final BooleanProperty activeProperty() {
        return this.active;
    }
    public final boolean isActive() {
        return this.activeProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setActive(final boolean active) {
        this.activeProperty().set(active);
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeObject(getName());
        out.writeInt(getValue());
        out.writeBoolean(isActive());
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty((String)in.readObject());
        this.value = new SimpleIntegerProperty(in.readInt());
        this.active = new SimpleBooleanProperty(in.readBoolean());
    }

    // Quick test:
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Item testItem = new Item("Item", 42, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        oos.writeObject(testItem);
        oos.close();
        byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
        Item result = (Item) in.readObject();
        System.out.println(result.getName());
        System.out.println(result.getValue());
        System.out.println(result.isActive());
    }
}
```

With this approach, the `CheckBoxTableCell` will automatically bind to the property returned by the`PropertyValueFactory`.

The alternative is to create a `BooleanProperty` specifically for the purpose of binding to the check box selected state. Note that, according to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html), because the `CheckBoxTableCell` never enters or leaves an editing state, the editing callbacks `onEditCommit` etc are never invoked:

> Note that the CheckBoxTableCell renders the CheckBox 'live', meaning
>   that the CheckBox is always interactive and can be directly toggled by
>   the user. This means that it is not necessary that the cell enter its
>   editing state (usually by the user double-clicking on the cell). A
>   side-effect of this is that the usual editing callbacks (such as on
>   edit commit) will not be called. If you want to be notified of
>   changes, it is recommended to directly observe the boolean properties
>   that are manipulated by the CheckBox.

Here's a demo using this technique. Again, I don't really recommend this approach, as you end up creating a bunch of `BooleanProperty`s which are quickly eligible for garbage collection. The intended approach is for the model to use JavaFX properties.

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewCheckBoxTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Name", "name"));
        table.getColumns().add(createColumn("Value", "value"));

        TableColumn<Item, Boolean> activeCol = createColumn("Active", "active");
        table.getColumns().add(activeCol);

        activeCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
            CheckBoxTableCell<Item, Boolean> cell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>(index -> {
                BooleanProperty active = new SimpleBooleanProperty(table.getItems().get(index).isActive());
                active.addListener((obs, wasActive, isNowActive) -> {
                    Item item = table.getItems().get(index);
                    item.setActive(isNowActive);
                });
                return active ;
            });
            return cell ;
        });

        Button listActiveButton = new Button("List active");
        listActiveButton.setOnAction(e -> 
            table.getItems().stream()
                .filter(Item::isActive)
                .map(Item::getName)
                .forEach(System.out::println));

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
            .mapToObj(i -> new Item("Item "+i, i, false))
            .forEach(table.getItems()::add);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, null, null, listActiveButton, null) ;
        BorderPane.setAlignment(listActiveButton, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(listActiveButton, new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> createColumn(String title, String propertyName) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(propertyName));
        return col;
    }

    public static class Item implements Serializable {

        private String name ;
        private int value ;
        private boolean active ;

        public Item(String name, int value, boolean active) {
            this.name = name ;
            this.value = value ;
            this.active = active ;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public boolean isActive() {
            return active;
        }

        public void setActive(boolean active) {
            this.active = active;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: James, thanks for your great answer. I was just wondering if there is no way to bind the CheckBoxTableCell to a `boolean` type like you can do it with other primitive data types and `@Override` the setOnEditCommit Method.

Thank you for the examples tho!